# How to handle screen flip while progressbar is working?

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

I have a progressbar in my activity. When screen orientation is changed my progressbar start working from zero. How to save his state while orientation changes?

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (cnt = 1; cnt < max; cnt++) {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100 * randomNum / 50);
                    // refresh
                    h.post(updateProgress);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because when a screen orientation change happens the activity is recreated.

A suggestion I can give you is to save the progress somewhere independently of the activity and then fetch it again.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I understand this, but what exactly(number, instance) i need to save and which method?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your comment. However, what I can advise you is to have a static variable somewhere and when you load the progress bar check if this value has any data and, in that case, load the data. When you are changing the progress, also update that static variable.